# adding slack notification for android

Tags: android, python, android-studio, slack-api, gson

I am new to android. I am trying to integrate slack notification in my android app.

**What I mean:** I want any exceptions & errors in my android project to be raised in my slack channel.

W**hat I tried:** To call the slack integration API for the same, I am using GsonRequest(Reason is that I'm using GsonRequest for all the API calls, I want things to be uniform across the project).

This is the code which I have written so far:

```
public class slacknotification {
    public void notifySlack(Context context) {
        String Url = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/TXXXXXX/BXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        final Map<String, String> headers = CommonLibs.getBasicHeaders(context);
        final GsonRequest<T> request = new GsonRequest<>(Request.Method.POST, Url, class,headers,
                new Response.Listener<T>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(X) {
                         #code
                        }
                },
               new Response.ErrorListener() {
                         #code
               }

    });
}
```

I am not aware of the values of T and X in my code. The response for

```
requests.request(
        method='POST',
        url=,'https://hooks.slack.com/services/TXXXXXX/BXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
        data='{"text": "' + "msg" + '"}',
        headers={'Content-type': 'application/json'},
    )
```

in python is 200[OK]. Can someone please help me here.

Comment: So what's happening?  Any exceptions?

Comment: @nasch no i am not getting any exception. Its just that I am stuck at this place. and don't know how to proceed further

Comment: So you have no exception but nothing appears in the slack channel?

Comment: for the data value you encapsulated `msg` in quotation marks, so it will be interpreted as text. I am guessing you wanted to use a variable so you may want to remove the quotation marks.

`data='{"text": "' + msg + '"}',`